# as3: using a variable with removeChild

Tags: actionscript-3

I would like to '`removeChild()`' using a variable in **actionscript 3**. Code is below -

```
var movieNumber:int=1;
removeChild(getChildByName("video_"+movieNumber));
```

I don't get any error messages, it just doesn't work.

Comment: What does `getChildByName("video_"+movieNumber)` return?

Comment: Try var movieName:String = "video_"+1; removeChild(getChildByName(movieName));

Comment: (Kind of merging h2ooooooo's comment and AzzyElvul's answer.)  In particular, how is it not working?  Is it not returning what you want?  Is it only removing one object when you want it to remove more?  Is something else wrong with it?  Because there are legitimate cases in which this is pretty much exactly how you would set things up.  We need more context.

Answer (score 1):

The code is fine. Maybe you have more than 1 clips with same name "video_1" in this case the code will remove only the first clip.